# Could not get any response azure storage table using API

Tags: azure, api, azure-table-storage

I want to get data from azure storage table, I tried using below request:

```
https://<xxxx>.table.core.windows.net/testTable()
```

But it returns below message:

```
<error 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<code>ResourceNotFound</code>
<message xml:lang="en-US">
The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:21b27073-d002-009d-3c4b- 
e5d267000000 Time:2020-02-17T04:34:09.2754288Z
</message>
</error>
```

Comment: How exactly did you test (I presume) the request that you mention in your question?  You've really not given much to go on here.  If you tested this via some code that makes a HTTP, then include that in your question.  With the information we have now, we can only conclude that a table `testTable` doesn't exist at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. You're making an `anonymous` request to Azure Table Storage which is not allowed. All requests to Azure Tables must be authorized.

You can learn more about this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-requests-to-azure-storage.